# HttpResponse wont work

Tags: java, android, httpresponse

So when i try to run the following code i can never ever get past the response line. what am i doing wrong?  I have allowed internet access in my manifest file.  I must be missing something huge because ive seen about 100 similar examples that have the exact same code as i do.  I've even built sample projects just to run these few lines and they all act the same way. please please help (the end goal is to make this work with https as well but any progress to make it work with http is good enough for me)

```
try{

                        HttpClient myHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost myHttpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/index.html?clientLanguage=eng");
                       //^Ive tried about 10 different sites (http and https) none of them work

                        //NEVER GETS PAST THE LINE BELOW, JUMPS TO THE LAST CATCH BLOCK OF THE EXCEPTION
                        HttpResponse response = myHttpClient.execute(myHttpPost);
                        //NEVER GETS PAST THE ABOVE LINE...

                        String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                        json= new JSONObject(data);
                    //parse the JSONObject
                       } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                         catch (ClientProtocolException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                         catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                         catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                         catch (NullPointerException e){ Log.e("My APP", "exception: " + e.getMessage());}
                         catch (Exception e ) {Log.e("My APP", "exception", e);} 


10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974): exception
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at com.example.httpstuff.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-17 15:31:41.423: E/My APP(974):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When an exception gets caught in the last catch statement, what type of exception is it?

Comment: do i have my catch and log statements set up correctly (still trying to get better at understanding log cat)? above are my relevent(in my eyes) logcat results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Looking up NetworkOnMainThreadException, we get [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). What it means is that you can't run an HTTP request on the main thread of your app, but only when you target Honeycomb.

So, the easiest way to fix this is to target a different Android version. Maybe 2.3, or up to Jellybean. Another way to solve it is to set up an AsyncTask to run the HTTP request.

If it works for you to target a different Android version, do that. If not, I can help you out with the AsyncTask. However, keep in mind that they highly reccommend that you *don't* run networking requests on your main thread.

As for AsyncTasks, the best place to turn is always the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

The basic idea is that you extend the AsyncTask class, which makes you implement a doInBackground method. Then you create an instance of your new class, and call execute(). Here's a code snippet from the documentation:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}

new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: targetting 2.3 is the very lazy and dirty way to fix this.
You should always target the last version of Android.
Using an AsyncTask is the correct way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Awesome.  I would love to learn more about asynctasks. I just started teaching myself programming a few months ago but i learned a little bit about threading. I made a java swing app that did calculations while the UI did other things (hopefully async is similar).  Could you point me in the right direction and i can get back to you when im prepared?

Comment: i just upvoted you to offset that bad downvote.  I think you answered my quetion. Ill accept it as my answer after i finish solving this problem.  Where is the async stuff?

Comment: Sorry, I was just putting it in

Comment: After reading the documentation, i am unsure about one of the statements.  Under "threading rules" the document says  "The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.)"  does this mean that in my app ill only be able to get the HttPResponse once? what if i need to access the data 5 minutes later?

Comment: It just means that you'll need to instantiate a new DownloadFilesTask, in the above case, if you want to run the task again. You can't call execute() on the same AsyncTask object twice.